# bash: --argument vs -arg

Tags: bash, arguments, standard

In most scripts (but mainly bash) it's commonplace to see some arguments that are configured like so:

`bash-4.3:$ command --longer-argument -la`

Where did this originate from? I'm mainly just curious as to why this became effectively a unanimous standard. Is it mainly for readability?

Also, why not use something like

`bash-4.3:$ command -longer-argument`, where all CLI arguments are specified by only one dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be helpful (for `tar` but I think it can be extended to other programs as well):
https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_21.html

> Long options are meant to be obvious and easy to remember, and their meanings are generally easier to discern than those of their corresponding short options (see below). For example:
>
> $ tar --create --verbose --blocking-factor=20 --file=/dev/rmt0
>
> gives a fairly good set of hints about what the command does, even for
>   those not fully acquainted with tar.

Also this link [Standards for Command Line Interfaces](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces).

And here is a joke about GNU long options: https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/long-options.en.html

Usually running `command -h/--help` shows which options (short/long) the command provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disambiguate options with arguments from one another unless a double-dash denotes a long one and a single dash signifies a short one.

```
-f file
```

...would mean the `-f` option with its `file` argument

...whereas `--ffile` would be a wholly different option without an argument.